# WordPress setup at tilde dev url

Tags: wordpress, url, installation

I have a shared hosting server with a WordPress installation. I access the URL via

`http://123.456.7.89/~mysite/`

I updated the `site_url` in `wp_options` table to be `http://123.456.7.89/~mysite/` - I can access the wp-admin and see the landing page template (though it says:

```
Not Found
It looks like nothing was found at this location. Maybe try a search?
```

Trying to navigate to any other page redirects to the actual site url, `www.mysite.com`, which is not set up yet.

Anyone run into this, and know how to get WordPress to work with a dev url?

Answer (score 1):

The site URL is stored in multiple places in the WordPress database.  At the very least you'd need to update the `home` value in `wp_options`.  But that's unlikely to be the only thing.

I'd strongly suggest using the "Search and Replace for WordPress Databases Script" mentioned in the [Moving WordPress Codex Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#When_Your_Domain_Name_or_URLs_Change), which will update all references, including the PHP-serialized values that can break with a normal database `update`.